# Parsing JSON data from TCP stream

Tags: c++, json, stream, nlohmann-json

I am using nlohmann's json library for parsing json data from a TCP stream. I am not quite sure how to handle partial json reads from local socket. Suppose that in the first read() I get:

```
{ 
    "MessageType": "CancelOrder",
    "Account":11111, 
    "CustomerNo":11111,
    "Side":"A",
    "DestinationMarket":"DUMB_MARKET",
    "Symbol":"DUMB_SYMBOL",
    "PositionEffect":"D",
    "Limi
```

and in the following read() from socket, I get:

```
    tPrice":0,
    "Quantity":1,
    "OrderType":"DUMB_TYPE",
    "StopPrice":0,
    "TimeInForce":"01.06.1999",
    "ExpireDate":0,
    "OrderID": "DUMB_ID",
    "IsStopOrder":"DUMB_STOP",
    "CorrelationId": 456
}
```

Partial reads cannot be parsed by the library since they are not valid. Does the library offer a solution to this? Or should I implement a solution myself?

What should be the best practice here?

Comment: A passable solution would be to merge all strings after individual reads from the socket until a trailing `}` is found at the end of the string. Then, you can proceed to process the JSON.

Comment: This is a low latency application and I am afraid that this naive solution would degrade performance. It could take long time to encounter a closing curly bracket at the end of the string.

Comment: low latency applications should not use JSON-related RPCs (In fact, there is no good industrial-grade technical solution), it's recommended to try grpc or fbthrift.

Comment: Send `length` before `content` like `HTTP` header.

Comment: A potential solution would be to take as many valid keys as you get in each read, and insert a `}` after them, parse them, and then when more keys come in repeat and merge the objects together. I'm unsure what the performance of this would be, but I suspect not much better than concatenating all the data as @Ruks suggested.

Comment: I've worked on a project which used JSON over IPC. If you are definitely stuck using this data format, I have a couple suggestions -
1. Use a message-oriented IPC library instead of raw TCP. We used ZeroMQ, guaranteeing that we didn't get partial messages like this.
2. Don't send data a stringified JSON if possible. We hit major performance issues with numerical data due to frequent string<->double conversions.

As noted above, something other than JSON is potentially better; but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten some good answers in the comments. I'm going to assemble some and add one more choice.

If you have control over both ends of the communications, then some people feel you should change the communications in one of two ways:

- Send the length of text first
- Or use a smarter messaging system over the socket

Either of these would solve your problem for you.

I'll offer two more possible choices.

- Send an "end of data" indicator -- something that won't appear in the JSON. For instance, a null-byte. Break before the EOD character.
- Try successively parsing data until it parses successfully.

The second one is kind of ugly. You'd parse `{` and get an exception. Then you'd parse `{"` for an exception, over and over until finally you have complete JSON. I bet it's slow, but it might work, and it doesn't depend on changing the data stream in any way.

Personally, I'd consider in order:

1. Use a proper messaging protocol
2. Use an End of Data indicator
3. Send the length
4. The hack of parsing and catching the exceptions until it parses

I think any of these would work. The last one is the only one that doesn't force you to change both ends of your data stream.